# How do I properly test the char[ ] fields in my custom object for nulls, blanks, or empty? and Why do char[ ] indicate a length of 11?

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, reflection, initialization

I am researching how to use reflection to initialize a custom object. As an example,
my object has several fields of differing types, however NONE of the fields are of the
String type. I used chararrays instead of strings because I want to clear the objects 
out and not worry about immutable Strings being around in the heap should the applictation crash.

In addition, because the class implements CharSequence, the static fields
buff, offset, and count are required. Also worth mentioning, the getters and setters are
synchronized since this object will be used in a multi-threaded environment. Finally, 
there is a custom list of Person objects called People which lives in its own People.java file and
is a customized collection of Person objects. Additional details about the object are elided for brevity.

The question is, how do I test for empty, blank, or null fields in my Person object? In my main class,
I want to test for null, empty, or blank before inserting said object into a backend database. I have
tried creating both a `Person.isNull()` and a similar `Person.hasNull()` function to test for empty values
in the `char[]` fields, but the results are ABSOLUTELY NOT what I expected. The println statemnt inside
the test for isCharArray revealed some THINGS I CURRENTLY DO NOT UNDERSTAND.....

Here is some sample output:

```
Size of byte: 1 bytes.
Size of short: 2 bytes.
Size of int: 4 bytes.
Size of long: 8 bytes.
Size of char: 2 bytes.
Size of float: 4 bytes.
Size of double: 8 bytes.
buff: char[] 11
personID: char[] 11
personTitle: char[] 11
personFirstName: char[] 11
personLastName: char[] 11
```

which was created using the following System.out.println statement:

```java
System.out.println(f.getName() + ": " + f.getType().getCanonicalName() + " " +  String.valueOf(value).length());
```

and raises 2 questions:

1. Why 11?!!!!!
2. How do I properly test for blank, empty, or zero-length fields?!!!

Please help....

```java
public class Person  implements Serializable, 
                                Comparable<Person>,  
                                CharSequence, 
                                Cloneable   { // the object to model

    //  Fields 0, 1, and 2 are required to implement CharSequence                                   
    //  http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/implementsCharSequence.htm
    private  static char[] buff = {'\0'};   // No static fields are ever                    // Field 0
    private  static int offset  = 0;        // written to file. Their values                // Field 1
    private  static int count   = 0;        // must be reconstructed.                       // Field 2  

    // default serialVersion id
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7891011129876814235L;                      // Field 3
    private final static LocalDateTime rightNow = LocalDateTime.now();  

    private long   localSerialVersionUID= serialVersionUID;  //1st field written to file    // Field 4  
    private LocalDateTime personCreatedDateTime= rightNow;                                  // Field 5 
    private LocalDateTime  personLastUpdate    =  rightNow; // (YYYY-MM-DD)                 // Field 6  
    private char[] personID              = {'\0'}; // (PK)  possibly int auto increment     // Field 7 
    private char[] personTitle           = {'\0'};                                          // Field 8 
    private char[] personFirstName       = {'\0'};                                          // Field 9 
    private char[] personLastName        = {'\0'};                                          // Field 10 
    private LocalDate   personDOB        =  LocalDate.parse("1010-10-10"); // (YYYY-MM-DD)  // Field 11



    public Person( 
            final long serialUID,                           //4        
            final LocalDateTime createdDateTime,            //5 
            final LocalDateTime lastUpdate,                 //6
            final char[] id,                                //7 
            final char[] title,                             //8 
            final char[] firstName,                         //9 
            final char[] lastName,                          //10 
            final LocalDate   DOB                           //11                                                   
    ) {                                                
        this.localSerialVersionUID(serialUID);           //4 
        this.personCreatedDateTime(LocalDateTime.now()); //5 
        this.personLastUpdate(lastUpdate);               //6
        this.personID(id);                               //7 
        this.personTitle(title);                         //8 
        this.personFirstName(firstName);                 //9 
        this.personLastName(lastName);                   //10
        this.personDOB(DOB);                             //11
    }   

    public boolean hasNull() {
        Field fields[] = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field f : fields) {
            f.setAccessible(true);

            try{
                    Object value = f.get(this);
                    if ( value == null) {return true; } // default condition

                    boolean isCharArray =  f.getType().getCanonicalName().equals("char[]" );


                    // No need to check fields that are not char[]
                    if (( isCharArray) ) {      

    // ************* this compiles and executes (doesn't crash), but it doesn't produce intended results *********

                        System.out.println(f.getName() + ": " + f.getType().getCanonicalName() + " " +  String.valueOf(value).length());

                        if ( String.valueOf(value).length() == 0)  {return true;}
                        if ( String.valueOf(value).isEmpty())      {return true;}
                        if ( String.valueOf(value).isBlank())      {return true;}
                        if ( String.valueOf(value).equals('\0'))   {return true;}

                    }   

    // ************* this compiles and executes (doesn't crash), but it doesn't produce intended results *********


                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }         


    //enter code here


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        People<Person> people = new People()<>; //customized list of person objects
        People<Person> people2 = new People()<>; //customized list of person objects

        Person thomas = new Person().personFirstName("Thomas".toCharArray()); 
                // all other char array fields = {'\0'}
        people.add(thomas);

        Person sybil =  new Person().personFirstName("Sybil".toCharArray()); 
                // all other char array fields = {'\0'}
        people2.add(sybil);

        if (!thomas.hasNull() ){    // ******* currently this test fails and a Person gets inserted to the People list
            People.insertPerson(thomas);
        }
        if (!sybil.hasNull() ){     // ******* currently this test fails and a Person gets inserted to the People list
            People.insertPerson(sybil);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, it helps, when you print the result of `String.valueOf(value)`. Then, you will understand. Besides that, stop trying to program Java as if it was C. There’s no sense in trying re-implement zero terminated strings. Java’s arrays do not work like C’s arrays and Java’s strings are not zero terminated char arrays.  When you want strings, use `String` and learn how strings work in Java. Further, don’t implement `CharSequence` nor `Cloneable` for no reason. There’s also no sense in creating a **constant** `rightNow` and assign the same value to each object as its alleged creation time.

Comment: 1/3 Tyvm for the reply. However, I'm not sure  that I need to follow ALL (only some) of your advice. For example, use of rightNow() is to create a 30 member set of objects (e.g. a location object that is associated with a person object, and a school object that is associated with its own location object) with timestamps to facilitate record coordination. Conceptually, the objects are being created in the same timeframe but secs and millisecs, even mins might differ depending on how slow the processor is or on how close the TOD is to rolling over to another date/time). Is there a better way?

Comment: 2/3 In addition, I know how to Strings, but I am seeking a way around the fact that java strings are immutable and changes simply put more strings on the heap. I need to use a string then dispose of it right away and with char sequences I can null the char[ ] by simply looping through the individual characters. Again, might you know a better way. I am honestly open to an alternative way to manage this, but all of my research suggest that Strings are versions of char sequences anyway, without the limitation of immutability. Am I misinformed?

Comment: 3/3 I agree that I should not implement cloneable for just any reason (as is the case for charsequence, but I just explained why I needed that). Nevertheless, I have to persist my objects by more than 1 method (i.e. to a database, to a hidden flat file, to an xml file), etc. and each of the data points must be identical. Perhaps you also have a suggestion for a better way to accomplish this. Again, thanks for the reply.

Comment: 1) There is no problem with creating multiple objects with the same timestamp, but a `final static` field *never* changes, so in the shown code, all objects have the same timestamp. The solution is already shown in your code, just receive the timestamp as constructor argument. If that’s the only constructor, assigning the never changing value of the `final static` field before overwriting it with the constructor argument is pointless anyway.

Comment: 2) Java arrays have a fixed length, so your arrays initialized with `{'\0'}` can never hold more than one character. You will have to replace them with other array objects for most practical purposes. I guess, the setter method you haven’t show does already assign the reference instead of overwriting the array contents. So it’s rather Cargo Cult Programming, using arrays like strings. You’ve created five one-length arrays before overwriting their references with pointers to other arrays. Had you used `String` and initialized the fields with `""` there was only one object instead of five.

Comment: But anyway, for most cases, Garbage Collection will work more efficient than code that has to copy data every time it is passed around. 3) I don’t see any explanation of why you need to implement `CharSequence`. Your code doesn’t use that feature and any attempt to use that feature, given that it is implemented atop `static` fields with no relationship to the instances, would yield catastrophic results. It’s not clear what “each of the data points must be identical” exactly means, but even less, how `Cloneable` comes into play. This interface has only one purpose, support the `clone()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String.valueOf().length() returns 11 because that is the number of digits/characters in the output (i.e. [@936016386 - an address - has 11 characters)